# Slot Machine in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made this program which simulates a slot machine.

```
import random, time, os

def input_verify(message):
    while True:
        user_input = input(message).lower()
        if user_input in ("yes", "no"):
            return user_input
        print("Invalid Input")

def win(number_of_matches, fruit):
    global balance
    print("Well done! You got", number_of_matches, "of the same fruit!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    reward = fruits[fruit][1] * number_of_matches
    print("You won £{}!".format(reward))
    balance += reward

fruits = {"apple": [10000, 1], "banana": [7000, 1.5], "lemon": [6000, 1.75], "orange": [5000, 2], "kiwi": [4000, 4],
          "peach": [3000, 6], "avocado": [2000, 10], "grapes": [1000, 20], "mango": [500, 100], "melon": [1, 10000]}
weighted_fruits = [fruit for fruit in fruits for i in range(fruits[fruit][0])]

print("Welcome to my slot machine! Each turn costs £1.")
balance = 10
if os.path.exists("One Armed Bandit.txt"):
    with open("One Armed Bandit.txt", "r") as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
    continue_saved_game = input_verify("Do you want to continue your saved game?")
    if continue_saved_game == "yes":
        balance = float(contents[1].strip())

time.sleep(0.5)
print("\nYour current balance is £{}.\n".format(balance))
time.sleep(1)
while True:
    balance -= 1
    reward = 0
    a, b, c = [random.choice(weighted_fruits) for i in range(3)]
    print("Spinning...")
    for fruit in (a, b, c):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(fruit)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if a == b == c:
        win(3, a)
    elif a == b or a == c or b == c:
        if b == c:
            win(2, c)
        else:
            win(2, a)
    else:
        print("Unlucky. None of your fruits matched each other.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("\nYour current balance is £{}.\n".format(balance))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    replay = input_verify("Do you want to play again?")
    if replay == "no":
        save = input_verify("Do you want to save your game?")
        if save == "yes":
            name = input("What is you name?")
            with open("One Armed Bandit.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write("{}'s Balance:\n{}".format(name, balance))
        break
```

I don't like how there are so many `time.sleep()` calls scattered throughout my code. Is there a way to achieve the same thing but in a cleaner way. Moreover, could you suggest some ways to make it more efficient?

Comment: Isn't using asking "could you suggest some ways to make it more efficient?" in conflict with using `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Yes. That is why I don't like the time.sleep() but the delays provide a better experience for the user.@Peilonrayz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code,

You should write code to adhere to the PEP8 standard, for the most part you've done that correctly, you have `snake_case` variable and function names, but you've put all your imports on one line.

```
import random, time, os
```

should become

```
import random
import time
import os
```

Give one line per import.

Your code lacks a main guard. If I was to import any functions or classes from your current code, your slot machine game would start! Generally you just want to wrap your `main` code in a conditional check that looks like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

where `main` is a function that starts the execution of your program.

A pattern you use in your code is relying on a string value ("yes" or "no") to determine which function executes. This is standard enough and nothing really wrong with it, but I would recommend instead of checking for this string literals, to use boolean values instead which are taken from shorter helper functions. A quick example.

You offer the ability to save and load game state, this is a good thing. However, you save the state in a **Human readable** fashion - i.e. "Bob's Balance: 24". Unless you're relying on this format somewhere else or even just displaying it, you could just save a single number in a file. No need to record a name.

The main code does a lot, you could break this up into helper functions. Some possible function names that jump out are.

`load_game`, `save_game`, `wants_to_save`, `wants_to_replay`

A pattern you use in your code is relying on a string value ("yes" or "no") to determine which function executes. This is standard enough and nothing really wrong with it, but I would recommend instead of checking for this string literals, to use boolean values instead which are taken from shorter helper functions. A quick example.

Your current code for prompting for saving the game

```
    replay = input_verify("Do you want to play again?")
    if replay == "no":
        save = input_verify("Do you want to save your game?")
        if save == "yes":
            name = input("What is you name?")
            with open("One Armed Bandit.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write("{}'s Balance:\n{}".format(name, balance))
        break
```

I would create some helper functions that look like

```
def wants_to_replay():
    return input_verify("Do you want to play again?") == "yes"

def wants_to_save():
    return input_verify("Do you want to save your game?") == "yes"

def save():
    name = input("What is you name?")
    with open("One Armed Bandit.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("{}'s Balance:\n{}".format(name, balance))
```

And then the code becomes

```
 if not wants_to_replay():
    if wants_to_save():
        name = input("What is you name?")
        with open("One Armed Bandit.txt", "w") as f:
           f.write("{}'s Balance:\n{}".format(name, balance))
    break
```

The presence of a `global` variable is a bit suspect. This usually indicates that maybe you should be using a class instead. Perhaps a `SlotMachine` object.

It might be nice to be able to instantiate a slot machine object and call a `start` method on it.

```
slot_machine = SlotMachine(saved_balance)
slot_machine.start()
```

this line,

```
a, b, c = [random.choice(weighted_fruits) for i in range(3)]
```

when there is an unused variable, you should indicate as such by naming it `_`
so this line becomes

```
a, b, c = [random.choice(weighted_fruits) for _ in range(3)]
```

But then `a`, `b` and `c` are not great variable names. They do have a small scope and are used immediately after, but there's no reason to not give them a better name.

Why not just call them `all_fruit` then in the next loop you can just use

```
for fruit in all_fruit:
    ...
```

In the next section you compare them to each other, you could simply then unpack these into variables like

```
fruit_a, fruit_b, fruit_c = all_fruit
```

I think single letter variable names (excluding `_` and loop counters) should be avoided at all costs.

You currently have all the fruits values hard coded in, it might be worth while to extract that data into a file to make it easier to add/remove new ones. That's probably not a huge deal though and may have no real benefit.

I'm not sure if there's any cleaner way to achieve the `sleep`s without scattering the calls throughout the code. You could maybe use named constants for the duration, but there may not be much value in that either.

You have no **docstrings** in your code. The `print` statements act as a form of documentation however, and your variable names are (mostly) very good. But there may be some room for some useful comments.

Hopefully this review was useful for you!

Comment: You repeated the part between `Thanks for sharing your code,` and `A quick example.` twice accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

@chatton already said that your fruits' characteristics should be stored in a separate file. I propose to read them in a list of [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s. For exmaple, your `Fruit` class definition will look like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Fruit = namedtuple('Fruit', ['name', 'weight', 'reward'])
```

And then after reading the fruits, you will have a list of `Fruit` instances like this:

```
fruits = [Fruit(name='apple', weight=10000, reward=1),
          Fruit(name='banana', weight=7000, reward=1.5),
          Fruit(name='lemon', weight=6000, reward=1.75),
          ...
          Fruit(name='melon', weight=1, reward=10000)]
```

---

> ```
> weighted_fruits = [fruit for fruit in fruits for i in range(fruits[fruit][0])]
> ...
> a, b, c = [random.choice(weighted_fruits) for i in range(3)]
> ```

You don't need this huge `weighted_fruits` list of thousands elements to get random items with weights. Instead you can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
weights = [fruit.weight
           for fruit in fruits]
while True:
    selected_fruits = random.choices(fruits,
                                     k=3,
                                     weights=weights)
    ...
```

---

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get fruits that were selected 2 or 3 times:

```
most_common_fruit, most_common_fruit_count = (Counter(selected_fruits)
                                              .most_common(n=1)[0])
if most_common_fruit_count == 1:
    print("Unlucky. None of your fruits matched each other.")
else:
    ...
```

---

Instead of a weirdly named function `win` you should have something like this:

```
def get_new_balance(original_balance: float,
                    *,
                    matches: int,
                    reward: float) -> float:
    return original_balance + reward * matches
```

No globals (really bad practice), no printing (it should be outside) and supplying amount of reward directly instead of a fruit itself. I added [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) as well. It's a good practice to include them. You help yourself and other people by being explicit about what type of data should be supplied to and returned from a function. And asterisk means that all arguments that follow after are keyword-only now:

```
if most_common_fruit_count == 1:
    print("Unlucky. None of your fruits matched each other.")
else:
    balance = get_new_balance(balance,
                              matches=most_common_fruit_count,
                              reward=most_common_fruit.reward)
```

---

Some other advises:

1. Don't read a savefile before asking if user actually wants to read it.
2. `float(contents[1].strip())` - there is no need to `strip` here.
3. `reward = 0` is never used.
4. Avoid hardcoding things like `'One Armed Bandit.txt'` or magic numbers like `balance = 10`. You could put them to a main function's signature as default parameters.
5. You could use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) if you are with Python 3.6: `print(f"You won £{reward}!")`.
6. Try to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide. @chatton already said about imports on separate lines. Also, don't exceed 79 characters on one line and separate functions by 2 blank lines.
7. `open("One Armed Bandit.txt", "r")` - you can omit `"r"` as it is default parameter.